# Javascript auto width detect then add two pixels to it

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript which detects the width of a html a tag, works completely fine but i'd like to increase the value by two for example or whatever value is set, please advise on how I would go about this? Thank you.

```js
$('.navbar-nav li a').each(function(index){
 $(this).width(function () {
  return $(this).width();
 });
});
```

```html
<ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6g90mLn/7/

Comment: `width()` is a getter/setter method. So `$(this).width( $(this).width() + 2 )` should do the job. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: @giorgio `.width` is not a setter. `.css('width', <value>)` should do the trick.

Comment: @KeesvanLierop it is.... check this; http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2

Comment: You are right @giorgio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `width` as setter and getter. See the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/width/

```js
$('.navbar-nav li a').each(function(index){
 $(this).width($(this).width() + 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you for your help. Likewise with the previous comment that was also great.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').each(function(index){
    var newWidth = $(this).width() + 2;
    $(this).css('width', newWidth);
});
```